# Como alterar o conteúdo de um arquivo dentro de um commit antigo no Git?

Tags: git

Tenho um arquivo que sofreu três alterações e foram feitos commits para cada alteração, quero alterar o conteúdo manualmente do primeiro commit para corrigir uma menção não autorizada.

Seria possível fazer algo assim, ou terei que refazer todos os commits? Lembrando que até o momento somente uma pessoa tem acesso ao projeto.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta no [StackOverflow internacional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git#answer-1186549), é bem simples o processo:

Primeiro se deve ir ao commit desejado:

```
git rebase --interactive b6f925df^
```

Depois altere `pick` para `edit` nos commits que você deseja modificar e em seguida rode:

```
git commit --all --amend --no-edit
```

Para finalizar rode:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Tem uma viso de atenção para essa abordagem pois todos os SHA-1 dos arquivos serão modificados e isso pode gerar graves problemas então pense muito bem antes de fazer isso.

Comment: It's works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer a alteração com o `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

Este comando vai abrir um editor com os últimos 3 commits e as instruções que deves seguir.

O que tu queres é no 3o commit trocar o `pick` por `reword`.

Depois de gravares este ficheiro ele vai abrir um novo editor com a mensagem do commit que queres mudar. Só tens de alterar a mensagem e gravar.

Atenção que se já fizeste push do commit que vais alterar podes ter de fazer `git push --force`

Nota: o `git push --force` nunca deve ser usado, excepto se souberes mesmo o que estás a fazer. Como neste caso disseste que só uma pessoa está  trabalhar no projecto, não deve haver problema.

Comment: Foi exatamente o que achei no stackoverflow internacional e postei abaixo.

Comment: Sim, também funciona ;)